# Can not overclock RPi 4

Tags: pi-4, overclocking

I'm following this guide: https://www.cnx-software.com/2019/07/26/how-to-overclock-raspberry-pi-4/

And when I run the command `vcgencmd get_config int | grep "arm\|over"` it tells me that `arm_freq=1400`.

Why is that? And how can I properly overclock my RPi 4?

Edit 2:

My OS is Raspbian Buster

Edit 1:

Some more info:
`rpi-update` gives me this

```
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Performing self-update
 *** Relaunching after update
 *** Raspberry Pi firmware updater by Hexxeh, enhanced by AndrewS and Dom
 *** Your firmware is already up to date
```

And `sudo apt dist-upgrade` gives me this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

My `/boot/config.txt` looks like this

```
# For more options and information see
# http://rpf.io/configtxt
# Some settings may impact device functionality. See link above for details

# uncomment if you get no picture on HDMI for a default "safe" mode
#hdmi_safe=1

# uncomment this if your display has a black border of unused pixels visible
# and your display can output without overscan
disable_overscan=1

# uncomment the following to adjust overscan. Use positive numbers if console
# goes off screen, and negative if there is too much border
#overscan_left=16
#overscan_right=16
#overscan_top=16
#overscan_bottom=16

# uncomment to force a console size. By default it will be display's size minus
# overscan.
#framebuffer_width=1280
#framebuffer_height=720

# uncomment if hdmi display is not detected and composite is being output
hdmi_force_hotplug=1

# uncomment to force a specific HDMI mode (this will force VGA)
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=51

# uncomment to force a HDMI mode rather than DVI. This can make audio work in
# DMT (computer monitor) modes
#hdmi_drive=2

# uncomment to increase signal to HDMI, if you have interference, blanking, or
# no display
#config_hdmi_boost=4

# uncomment for composite PAL
#sdtv_mode=2

#uncomment to overclock the arm. 700 MHz is the default.
#arm_freq=800

# Uncomment some or all of these to enable the optional hardware interfaces
#dtparam=i2c_arm=on
#dtparam=i2s=on
#dtparam=spi=on

# Uncomment this to enable infrared communication.
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir,gpio_pin=17
#dtoverlay=gpio-ir-tx,gpio_pin=18

# Additional overlays and parameters are documented /boot/overlays/README

# Enable audio (loads snd_bcm2835)
dtparam=audio=on

[pi4]
# Enable DRM VC4 V3D driver on top of the dispmanx display stack
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
max_framebuffers=2
force_turbo=0
arm_freq=2000
over_voltage=6

[all]
#dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
```

Comment: Is the firmware and O/S up to date?

Comment: that is odd, because without messing around at all, `arm_freq=1500` - so you managed to slow it down - so, what does your `/boot/config.txt` look like?

Comment: @Andyroo yes. I updated my question with more information, please read.

Comment: @JaromandaX huh? I *under*clocked it? haha. I updated my question with full `config.txt` content.

Comment: Wonder if it’s thermally throttled or not running flat out as it does not need it?  When config set what does lscpu give for CPU max MHz:?

Comment: @Andyroo hmmm. it gives 1400.0000

Comment: Baffled - it may be worth moving the overclock away from the Pi 4 tag (guess) and starting at a lower value (say 1450) then step up  This post from Jan https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=29&t=261300&hilit=vc4+fkms+v3d+overclock infers not all Pis overclock to the same top speed.  (Bed time for me it’s gone 4AM)

Comment: @Andyroo I'm baffled too. Alright I guess I just have to continue experimenting. Thx for the effort.

Comment: You should not use `rpi-update` to fix problems, unless you know what you are doing. It installs untested and unstable drivers and firmware, only for testing. It will only increase your problems.

Comment: @ingo can i rever it?

Comment: Look at [Unstable rPi 4B after rpi-update](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/109432/79866), how to revert the rpi-update installation.

Comment: It seems as if the OC config must be under the section `[all]`, and not under `[pi4]` as suggested by the guide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving the overclock configuration from section `[pi4]` to section `[all]` fixed it.

Although my RPi seems to not be stable when overclocking over 1600 MHz.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
over_voltage=4
arm_freq=2001
arm_freq_min=400
#arm_64bit=1
```

Uncomment the last line if you are running a 64bit O/S

Comment: No go. Tried with and without the last line.